# config.xml in native app of cordova project gets updated everytime I build the project using Terminal command

Tags: java, android, cordova, plugins, native

I wanted to test the .java Plugin class which will help in the exposure of the methods that are available in the integrated .aar SDK. I have created the cordova project and integrated the .aar SDK file. I added the plugin class to src directory. I referred to http://moduscreate.com/plugin-authoring-cordova-6-ios-android/ for the changes that has to be done in the .js and .html files. I added the feature in config.xml (app's res directory). But everytime I run the command `cordova build android` the config.xml file gets reset. But If I run the app using Android studio it works fine. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

If you build through Command line, every time it will replace your platform config.xml file with config.xml file(exist in your project folder). If you want to build an app with your custom plugin then you should add a plugin through cli(it wont accept manual installation).

Please follow [this link](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Just saw the other answer and it is not much different from mine. Should have checked before I answered.

**Original**

The config.xml in platform folders get replaced with the config.xml in the projects root folder everytime you build. Either change this one or add plugins through the command line and Cordova will edit it for you.